# Rubymine x64 (Win) SDK Error (Ruby SDK not found)

Tags: ruby, windows, sdk, 64-bit, rubymine

I have installed Rubymine 2017.3.3 x64 and could not find an installed Ruby SDK.
I choosed the rubyminex64.exe, restarted and beeing confrontated now with repeating errors on startup. Curiously the Errors points to Desktop but there is nothing than the shortcuts which has something to do with Ruby.

```
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\-e
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\puts
   RUBY_DESCRIPTION.strip; puts RUBY_PATCHLEVEL.to_s
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\-e
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\print RUBY_VERSION
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\-e
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\print(defined?(RUBY_PATCHLEVEL) ? RUBY_PATCHLEVEL : 0)
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\-e
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION.strip; puts RUBY_PATCHLEVEL.to_s
 - Cannot find file C:\User\myUsername\Desktop\puts $:
```

I tried to reinstall but same effects... Any ideas ?

Comment: Take a look here https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_Rubymine_on_Windows

Comment: I did. Same errors but points to .../Dekstop/./